# Getting fixed left element and fluid right element

Tags: html, css

I think it's Friday so I'm having a brain fart.  I can't for the life of me setup a page with a fixed left element `<aside>` about 200px and a fluid width right element `<article>` that takes up the remaining space.

Simple but I'm having issues with block, inline issues.

A push in the right direction would be great!

http://jsfiddle.net/pcEbG/

```
<style>
aside {
    width: 200px;
}

aside, article {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>


<section>
    <aside>
    This is a section
    </aside>


    <article>
    This is an article that should take up the remaininfg width
    </article>

</section>
```

Comment: Post your html and css or jsfiddle

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698900/css-two-column-full-width

Comment: Posted my code and fiddle..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your browser requirements are, but if you know that the aside is a fixed width, for the width of the fluid container you can always use:

```
width: calc(100% - 200px);
```

Here is the browser compatibility for calc http://caniuse.com/#search=calc