# Float DIV containing image to right of text where container must be fluid

Tags: css

I need to float an image to the right of some text. The Div and text are both contained within numerous DIVs and I cannot change the HTML, only the CSS.

I thought this would be easy but for some reason I cant figure it out. The containing element cannot but a fixed width as this is a responsive site.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cgznB

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. </p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="image-cont">
  <div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRMFGfVlnjbzD3dekwhIZ8yPYCzYuKInbzRNc9hU5doTPsPI51a" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.image-cont {
  float: right;
}
div {
  display: inline;
}
```

UPDATE - I can achieve this with the following but I would rather than the image be its full width and only the text be fluid.

```
.image-cont {
  float: left;
  width:30%;
}
div > div > div {
  float: left;
  width:70%;
}
```

Comment: If you need to use a fixed-width image, then maybe [Adaptive Design](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/what-is-the-difference-between-responsive-vs-adaptive-web-design/) is an option. Note that as soon as you introduce fixed-width elements you can only go so far with responsive design, that's why Donovan's answer below is the correct solution. Here's a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KUc6V/5/) I put together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this CSS to fix your problem.

```
.image-cont {
  float: left;
  width:30%;
}
div > div > div {
  float: left;
  width:70%;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to have a fixed width for the image and a fluid width for the text. Is this possible? Ill updated my answer to clarify this.

Comment: If you want a responsive design, it's not possible to fix the image width. You can modify the width with `.image-cont img` to adjust it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195836/2-column-div-layout-right-column-with-fixed-width-left-fluid) one?

```
.container {
   height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
    width: 180px;
    float: right;
    background: #aafed6;
}

.left {
    float: none; /* not needed, just for clarification */
    background: #e8f6fe;
    /* the next props are meant to keep this block independent from the other floated one */
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}​​
```

Comment: Close, but I need my text to be before the image. In this example the fixed width div (which would be my image) is before the text.