# Two columns layout with aligned div

Tags: html, css

[2 column div layout: right column with fixed width, left fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195836/2-column-div-layout-right-column-with-fixed-width-left-fluid)

**I have the same problem, only in the code box on the right goes first, second left**

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  min-width: 1024px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}

/*left block */
    .block_side {
        width: 236px;
        height: 400px;
        float: left;
        margin: 19px 0 0 30px;
    }


/* Right block */    
.content_side {
        float: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    }
```

**content_side** be right and left **block_side**, but they must have the document in that order

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="content_side">
     {CONTENT}
   </div>
   <div class="block_side">
     {BLOCK}
   </div>
 </div>
```

**"content_side" replaces a unit that should be left, occupies the entire available width**

[Demo in Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhqu4/2/)

Comment: Can you describe your specific problem?

Comment: "content_side" replaces a unit that should be left, occupies the entire available width

Answer (score 1):

change **#containet** to **#container**  and **text-align: left;** to **text-align: center;**

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  min-width: 1024px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhqu4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Change css rule float:none to float:right would do the trick if I understand your question correctly.

```
.content_side {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Could you try to be more specific what the problem is? It's not easier to help you just because you write "!!!!!".

Comment: sorry..   "content_side" replaces a unit that should be left, occupies the entire available width

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  min-width: 1024px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
}

/*left block */
    .block_side {
        width: 256px;
        height: 400px;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px 0 0 30px;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */

    background-color:green;
    }


/* Right block */    
.content_side {
        float: right;
        width: 738px;
        margin: 0;
    height:400px;
    overflow:auto;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */

    background-color:red;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="block_side">
     {BLOCK}
   </div>
   <div class="content_side">
     {CONTENT}
   </div>
 </div>
```

You need to float:left or float:right your blocks (side and content).

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sawyer/j6fAM/)

More about box-sizing trick here: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: block_side must be a fixed-width 256px

Comment: Does not work, the block_side should be left with a width of 256px and the content_side stretch and should be on the right..

Comment: ANd block_side tinue to be after content_side from html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195836/2-column-div-layout-right-column-with-fixed-width-left-fluid   I have the same problem, only in the code box on the right goes first, second left