# Float not working as it should

Tags: html, css

I am trying to float something to the right but it doesn't work as it should.
I am trying to get something like eu-accounts.com > right banner with the Classes.

This is what I've got now

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <title> Haltqt - Accounts </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="banner">

  </div>

  <div id="content">
    hier komt content
    <div id="product">
       Products will come here
    </div>
 </div>
 <div id="classen"> hier komen de classes
 </div>

 </body>

 <footer> &copy Haltqt-accounts.com </footer>

</html>
```

and the css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#banner {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:100%;
height:300px;
background-color:#000; /* deze staat nu op zwart, dit is de banner. dit moeten we op transparant zetten en in de body een wallpaper als achtergrond om het effect te krijgen van eu-accounts.com*/ 
}

#content {
margin: 0 auto;
padding:0;
width: 70%;
background-color:yellow;
}

footer{
margin: 0 auto;
padding:0;
width: 70%;
text-align:center;
}

#classen {
width:15%;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
float:right;
background-color:red;
}

#product {
margin:5px;
padding:5px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y8j5hw5c/

Could you take a look why the class classen is not floating correctly? 
Thanks.

Comment: your #content div is still at block level. So it takes up the whole  width, pushing your #classen down. Hint: try to float your #content div and use the browser debugger in the future to pinpoint your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this as sizes are predefined :

```
#content {
   margin: 0 0 0 15%;
   padding:0;
   width: 70%;
   float:left;
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

You should also clear the float for the `footer` element with `clear: both;`.
P.S.: *You should put `footer` inside `body` element*.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8j5hw5c/4/)

Comment: How could I have overseen this... Thanks:)

Comment: when i did this, the footer tag goes in the middle of both content and classen. you should probably add footer{clear: both}

Comment: @notulysses will do in 2minutes;)

Comment: Although this has nothing to do with your problem, you should put your `<footer>` inside the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if there is a special reason why your footer tags are out of your body tags. Add the clear both to the footer. and add float left in the content.

```
footer{
margin: 0 auto;
padding:0;
width: 70%;
text-align:center;
clear: both;
}
#content {
   margin: 0 0 0 auto;
   padding:0;
   width: 70%;
   float:left;
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add another solution approach, a similar question has been asked and correctly answered here:
[2 column div layout: right column with fixed width, left fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195836/2-column-div-layout-right-column-with-fixed-width-left-fluid)

This method uses an additional container `div` which surrounds the two columns, to make the left column flexible and allow it to use any remaining space, while the right column keeps its fixed width.

A possible variant for your problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/kbe0m9ug/