# Side by side div where right div has fixed width

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I have two divs, #left and #right inside a #container. The left div is fluid. The right div has a fixed width. How can I get the left div to shrink or expand when resizing the browser while the right div stays in place?
Can't seem to make this work. Surprisingly, the opposite (left div fixed, right div fluid) is easy.

Thanks in advance for your help. Here's the code:

```css
#container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

#left {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#right {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">        
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 column div layout: right column with fixed width, left fluid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195836/2-column-div-layout-right-column-with-fixed-width-left-fluid)

Comment: Is support for IE9 or prior a requirement?  If not [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) makes such layouts significantly easier

Comment: @ Amos
The solution in that link is not perfect since it requires to change the order of the divs in the html file.

@ gapple
I'd prefer not to use Flexbox. :)

Comment: @Pema: If you'd bothered to look at the [answer with the _second-most_ votes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5195914/983430) of the duplicate question, you would've found that it quotes the exact same _alistapart_ article which you claim solved your problem...

Comment: @Amos: I did bother to look. I just didn't notice it the first time I read it because it was the second best rated answer and also an external link. 
When I did read that article, I posted the answer here so that it's easier for others to find. So, relax.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm completely relaxed. I'd rather have duplicates marked as duplicates than have the same issue floated around multiple times, though :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Here's the code above with some additions that make it work:

```css
div {
    margin: 0px;
}

#container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid grey;   
}

#left {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left; /*Add This*/ 
    margin-right: -200px; /*Add This*/ 
}

/*Add This new Div*/ 
#inside {
    margin-right: 200px; /*Add This*/
}

#right { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    float: right; /*Add This*/
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="inside">    <!--Add This-->  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the website that helped me: http://alistapart.com/article/negativemargins

Comment: Brilliant, cross-browser safe solution! Works down to IE8, possibly even below that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the right floated div before the left (fluid) div and add float right to #right

here is the working example
http://jsfiddle.net/936u0d3b/

```css
#container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

#left {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#right {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="right">
    </div>
    <div id="left">        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without changing the div order?

Comment: If you can use table, table-cell styles. check this http://jsfiddle.net/sabinprakash/936u0d3b/1/

Answer (score 0):

Although Pema answered his/her question perfectly, here's another simple approach without change of markup that works down to IE9:

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

#left {
    width: calc(100% - 100px); /* added */
    float: left; /* added */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* added */
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#right {
    float: right; /* added */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* added */
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">        
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    </div>
</div>
```