# Avoid overlapping divs horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to modify CSS or do a javascript for success two conditions:

Example:
(------------------main div-----------------------------)(------right div -----)

Conditions:
1) If there are a div in the right of my main div, display my main div like the example.
2) If the right div dont exist, my main div must get all width.

I can set width with a determinated size but this dont meet all conditions.

Somebody can help me?.

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried? Where have you gone wrong?

Comment: This is a duplicate of _countless_ questions, try searching the site using different keywords.

Comment: Post what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered here : [2 column div layout: right column with fixed width, left fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195836/2-column-div-layout-right-column-with-fixed-width-left-fluid)

Use `width:auto` and `overflow:hidden` css styles for your main div so that it takes only the required width.

Example HTML :

```
<div class="right">
    right div fixed width
</div>
<div class="left">
    left main div flexible width
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.right {
  width: 180px;
  float: right;
  background: #aafed6;
}

.left {
  width: auto;
  background:blue;
  overflow: hidden;
 }​​
```