# 2-column CSS one responsive another fixed

Tags: html, css

I need two columns, one responsive, another fixed with `100px width`

For example left columns have `100px width` and right columns have the remaining width

In this simple code how much to put the width?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .main{
            display: table;
            clear: both;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #left{
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
        }
        #right{
            float: right;
            /*width: ;*/
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="left">
            left
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            right
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this looks like it might help just swap the left for right and the 180 pixel to 100 pixels  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195836/2-column-div-layout-right-column-with-fixed-width-left-fluid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using `display: table`  on the parent, set the children's display to `table-cell` and give a width to the first one like you did. The second column will automatically take the remaining width.

```
#left{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
}

#right{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Example : https://jsbin.com/dicuvigaka/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calc()` to calculate the remaining width. Check the browser compatibility table: [**Can I use calc()**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main {
  width: 100%;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}
#right {
  float: left;
  background-color: tomato;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div id="left">
      left
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      right
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```