# How to fill horizontally in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've got the following scenario:

```
div.container {
    min-width: 500px;
}

div.container div.left {

}

div.container div.right {

}

<div class="container">
    <div class="left">Fill-me</div>
    <div class="right">As-needed-only, align right</div>
</div>
```

I need the second div to be right-aligned in a row and be only as wide as needed, and left one to fill remaining space on the left. How can I achieve that?

ASCII-art:

```
[ Fill-me                        ][As-needed-only, align right]
```

---

XAML version of what I want to achieve:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <TextBlock>Right</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <Grid> <!-- Will fill rest of space -->
        <TextBlock>Left</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: what should happen if the content of the first div is more than a single row?

Comment: Easily possible with using flexbox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5195902/3675759

Comment: I cannot use flexbox (IE 8 compatibility :( )

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan The container should be expanded to fit everything inside. Edited the example from width to min-width.

Comment: @malcolm In answer you linked to the right div has fixed width. I need it to be variable width, matching its contents.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: table-cell` to child `div`'s and `display: table` to parent:

```css
div > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
div > div:first-child {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
div > div:last-child {
  background: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 500px;display: table;">
  <div>Fill-me</div>
  <div>As-needed-only, align right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: First (left) column should take all available space. You can make it with: 
div > div:first-child {width: 100%} div > div:last-child {white-space: nowrap}.

Comment: @skobaljic True. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best acheived easily by FLOATING, You have to float both left and right divs to right , then i prefer that you calculate width by % , like right 30%
the other div (left) will take the remaining space i think ..
give it a try

If you need the right div to take as much as space it needed , you have to do some calculations around like if you use php or other server side language, you can specify  the number of words of the line and upon this determine the width accordingly.

Comment: Right div should fill as much width as needed. That not necessairly will be 30%.