# CSS3: responsive centered row with variable size outter-elements

Tags: html, css, w3c

## Update 2

Following [@kidconcept](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3614691/kidconcept)'s new update about using the `table` tag, I have modified it to make a centered
[Table Timeline](https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/vjoj9e3p/). Note: copy-pasting [@kidconcept](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3614691/kidconcept)'s into a local project (not on JS Fiddle) did not have this property. I also added css selectors to make changing direction easier.

---

Thank you for considering my question.

I am trying to make a custom row. What I want to achieve is describe in more detail under the headings **description**.

In addition I am including a JS Fiddle, which gets me close (maybe) to what I want to achieve (e.g. I put some work in).

I don't really get CSS3 that well, and the tutorials at [W3-schools](http://www.w3schools.com) really only cover basics, however a deeper understanding of the difference between `display` options and what `float` actually does to the object is not readily given.

So I appreciate your assistance and am eager to learn from you :)

---

### Description

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/jvh7kco5/2/): A tri-element row with fixed size middle element

I am trying to make a row which contains exactly three elements. I want the middle element to have a fixed size and be centered. I want the other two elements (left / right) to have a fixed spacing to the middle element, but be responsive in size, see below:

[image]

In addition, I would like to stack these rows with a fixed spacing:

[image]

As well as be responsive to a small window size:

[image]

## Update

Using the answer from **@kidconcept** you can make a reasonable timeline.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: I think this is more easily solved with a table. Simply create a table with three columns and give a fixed width to the middle column.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td class="middle"></td>
  <td></tr>
</table>

td {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.middle {
  width: 10rem;
}
```

**Table Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/botbvanz/2/

---

Problematic Flex method: flex. Learn more about flex [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
<section class="tri-element-rows">
  <div class="left-element"></div>
  <div class="middle-element"></div>
  <div class="right-element"></div>
</section>

html, body {
  height: 100%
}
section {
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
}

div.middle-element {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

div.left-element,
div.right-element {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

div {
  background-color: coral;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

To achieve the effect simply put three elements within a `display: flex` box. Set the middle elements width to be fixed, in this case 15rem. Then give the left/right elements `flex-grow: 1`, which indicates they should fill the remaining space equally. Give all the divs a fixed margin, in this case 1rem.

For the heights, I'm not sure I understood your requirements exactly, but if you want the height of the inner divs to respond to the window you can set their height to be a % of the parent container. For this trick to work you need to remember to set the height of html and body to 100% (this gives them something to be a percentage *of*. In this case i set the section-height to be 50%, which means that two rows will always fill the screen. One other gotcha is that if you set a padding or a border to the section element, the element will become 50% *plus* the padding and border. To avoid this, set `box-sizing: border-box` on the section tag.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ksgd6r11/

Comment: thank you for your supportive comment and helpful post.  To clarify what I meant in regards to the variable height is shown in the JS Fiddle in my original post (e.g. the text drops down).  Shrinking the window width on your Fiddle does not have this property (but it isn't the most important). While adding text to JS Fiddle (to resemble mine) works, the text is offset when I embed it in my code.... Further, adding text shifts the middle element's position. How can this be fixed?

Comment: yeah, something like that.... if you do just a bit more editing, you can get this https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/t1j1snxu/4/  . However, while this renders in the JSFiddle, it behaves differently when I run it locally....

Comment: Also, open the JS Fiddle I linked above on your phone (or a small screen) and you will see that the middle element no longer stays in the middle.

Comment: it could be inconsistency with the flex implementation. Actually I should have suggested a table layout. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I like the table idea, however how can we guarantee that the middle element is always dead center?

Comment: see my new update. It seems to be working both locally and on JSFiddle, with the exception of the date being not as close to the image as the title for some reason.... It also, unfortunately, shoves the text behind the timeline when the screen is very small. Anyway to over come this? It also suffers from having long text mess up the size

Comment: You only need one table with multiple rows, simply your html and it will help you track down layout bugs more easily. About the text under the image. You could try setting position:relative with z-index to get the text over the image, but that won't help read the text at all. You should make the image smaller with a media query. About the date not lining up, that's probably some margin or padding collapsing. try setting all margin and padding to 0, * {margin:0;padding:0} to see if that fixes it. Use chrome developer tools to poke around at the elements and see what's causing what.

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest use a framework

- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/)

  and many more

It saves a lot of time and you can focus on logic

> they all have offset as one of their classes

However how we achieve the same in **Bootstrap** is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-2 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>

        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what it does it gives a padding left to the left most block

In your case.[check this(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/CliffyMk/sL77m6xe/)

or rather

```css
div.block{
  width:32%;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
  float:left;
  margin:2px;
}
div.block-2{
  width:31%;
  height:50px;
  float:left; border:1px solid black;
  margin:2px;
}
div.margin-l{
  margin-left:50px;
}
div.section-2{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:60%;
}
```

```html
<section class="tri-element-rows">
 <div class="block">
 
 </div>
  <div class="block">
 
 </div> <div class="block">
 
 </div>
 <div class="section-2">
 <div class="block-2 ">
   
 </div>
 <div class="block-2">
   
 </div><div class="block-2">
   
 </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with kidconcept that the flexbox flex-grow property is your best solution. [This article](http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html) is a good resource for getting started with flexbox. Some developers still shy away from the flexbox module, but it’s extremely useful and browser support [is great](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). That said, in the spirit of trying to help you learn a bit more, I created something close to what you’re asking for using simple floats.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8v6o2k4p/)

```
<section class="row">
  <div class="left">
      <p>Left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-block">
    <div class="center">
      <p>Center</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>Right</p>
    </div>
  <div>
  </section>

<section class="row">
  <div class="left">
      <p>Left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-block">
    <div class="center">
      <p>Center</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>Right</p>
    </div>
  <div>
</section>

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.left p, .right p {
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.left {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
.center {
  width: 140px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  background: #4FBA49;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.right-block {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.right {
  height: 100%;
  background: #FDCF1A;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}
```

On a more conceptual level, floats pull elements from the normal flow of things on the webpage, shifting them to the left or right and allowing text etc. to wrap around them. Honestly, they’re not all they’e cracked up to be imo and I’ve always found them an imperfect solution. [This article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/) gives a helpful overview of floats.

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195836/2-column-div-layout-right-column-with-fixed-width-left-fluid) helpful in understanding how to use floats together with `overflow: hidden` property, a useful concept that I used in my Fiddle. Finally, you'll probably also benefit from reading up on css grids as well, especially in the context of Bootstrap or some other framework. Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for your answer and useful links. I like your answer as well, but it also suffers from the same issue mine had, namely when the window is small, you the text overflows.